# Find most active user (daily)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to add a command to my discord bot to find the most active user of the day. I could save chat logs and search through them but I'm pretty sure there is an easier way.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming every message is cached, you can use [`Collection.prototype.reduce()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/general/welcome)

```js
const object = guild.members.cache.reduce(
  (acc, member) => (
    // add up the sum of messages sent in each channel by this member and add it to the object
    (acc[member.id] = guild.channels.cache.reduce((acc, channel) =>
      // filter only messages sent by the current member
      acc + channel.messages.cache.filter(
       (message) =>
        message.author === member &&
        // make sure the message was sent within the last day
        message.createdTimestamp > new Date(new Date().getDate() - 1)
      ).size, 0
    )),
    acc
  ),
  {}
);

// sort the object and return the ID of the most active member
const mostActive = Object.entries(object).sort(([, a], [, b]) => b - a)[0][0]
```